# Why my Post Titles are same in showing to users?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have writtern the code below for showing 4 last posts that I have written in a category with ID = 2. It works but the problem is that although the Titles of posts are not same in "All Posts" tab in WordPress, It shows same "Title" for each post. What is the problem ? Thanks.

```
<?php
$Args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'category' => 2 );
$Posts = get_posts( $Args );
foreach ( $Posts as $Post ) : setup_postdata( $Post );
?>

<div class="Post">
    <div class="Image">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Images/Fruits.png" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="Context">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="Title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p class="Text"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use capitals for variable names, in this context it must be $post instead of $Post to work properly. Your updated code would be the following:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'order'=> 'DESC', 'category' => 2 );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
?>

<div class="Post">
    <div class="Image">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/Images/Fruits.png" class="responsive-img">
    </div>
    <div class="Context">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="Title"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <p class="Text"><?php the_content(); ?></p>
    </div>
</div>

<?php 
endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```